# Android Lollipop native executable NDK 9 PIE executable support

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop

Previously I've been using the following make file (or similar) to build a native app with the NDK (version r9d):

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= nativeApp.c
LOCAL_MODULE := nativeApp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcutils libc 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:= libbinder liblog
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

However, Lollipop started enforcing that native applications were PIE. I've seen several solutions online and on S.O. and from that I've tried adding the following lines to address this issue:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fPIE
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fPIE -pie
```

It always builds fine but no matter what flags I use when I try to run it on the device I always get the PIE support error. I already have an environment set up around NDK r9d so I was trying to not have to go and change it but is that the only way to address this?

Comment: Did you figure out your issue?

Comment: I ended up patching the link executable to get rid of the check entirely; something it's a build environment issue but I don't know what's been messed up. I uninstalled several versions of the SDK and NDK (different locations as well) so my best guess is/was some artifact that stemmed from that.

Comment: If you do find a good solution, do not hesitate to answer your own questions so other can learn as well.